# scale default sans font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

Consider the following minimal document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}

Consider the algorithm \textsf{heapify} below.

Consider the algorithm $\mathsf{heapify}$ below.

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following output.

[image: sans-serif fonts]

The first one is clearly ugly: the algorithm name's x-height is too big compared to the times text. The second line looks better to me but at the expense of using math mode for something that's "morally" text. This not only messes up spacing in pseudocode but it also doesn't work when your next algorithm is called `make-heap`; I don't consider `$\mathsf{make}\textsf{-}\mathsf{heap}$` a solution.

Is there a simple way to set the `\textsf` font to match the `\mathsf` ones?

Note: using the default sans font (cmss?) together with Times and setting algorithm names in sans-serif within a text block are both decisions which are not mine to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve your objective as follows:

- Don't load the `times` package, as it is deprecated. Load either the `mathptmx` package or, if you prefer, the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` pair of packages. Update, July 2023: I'd go with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.
- Load the `helvet` package with the option `Scaled`. In my opinion, if you want the x-heights of the serif and sans-serif letters to be approximately equal, the default amount of scaling isn't quite right for use with the `Times Roman` serif text font. I'd therefore use the option `Scaled=0.86` instead of just `Scaled`.

Incidentally, the font employed by `\mathsf` in your example is *not* Helvetica but `Computer Modern Sans Serif`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{helvet}
\begin{document}
Consider the algorithm \textsf{heapify} below.

Consider the algorithm $\mathsf{heapify}$ below.
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I had assumed -- possibly erroneously -- that because you loaded the package `times`, you *wanted* to use Helvetica as the document's sans serif text font. If this assumption is incorrect, i.e., if you simply want to use Computer Modern Sans Serif (CMSS) alongside Times New Roman (TNR), *don't* load the `helvet` package -- and definitely don't load the `times` package either, since the `times` automatically sets up Helvetica as the sans-serif text font. It so happens that the x-heights of TNR and CMSS are fairly similar; there is hence no need to scale CMSS to make it "work" alongside TNR.

Comment: I don't see any mention of Helvetica in the question: doesn't the OP want Times + CMSS (scaled)?

Comment: That works for me. Just out of curiosity, is it possible to set the `\textsf` font to be the same as the math one (with textmode spacing/dashes etc.)?

Comment: @JosephWright - The file `times.sty` contains the instruction `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` -- Helvetica -- (along with, naturally, `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}` -- Times Roman). I believe that the inability to scale Helvetica is one of the reasons why the `times` package is considered deprecated.

Comment: @Bristol - please see the addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks - loading times through `mathptmx` definitely looks better. My instructions were to use "11pt Times" for the body and "not change any fonts" - though Helvetica (loaded through the times package) seems to be what most people are using for algorithm names. We'll see if they accept (or even notice) CMSS too.