# How to change the size of one font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

**REVISED**:

I am preparing an article using this template and class file, which includes
mathptmx. The provided sans serif does not match the height of the Roman, as
can be seen in the attached image, and I would like to adjust it to match.

[image: A height mismatch]

My generic question, "How can one change the size of just one font?" thus
seems to have broad applicability, but I am at the request of the community
also including a MWE. The end contains code for an alternative sans serif
font, which doesn't match the Times New Roman in size either, and is not
strictly part of a MWE, but for context, because I was also considering using
this font for the math sans.

Thus general answer allowing me to slightly resize whatever font, now and in future
works, would be most helpful to me.

## MWE follows

```
% \documentclass{CUP-JNL-FMS}
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names,table]{CUP-JNL-FMS}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\let\Bbbk\relax
\let\openbox\relax
\let\bigtimes\relax
\let\widebar\relax
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}             
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
T$\mathsf{T}\mathrm{T}$
\end{document}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{OT1}{kurier}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{bold}{OT1}{kurier}{bx}{n}
```

Comment: If a journal has asked you to use a template, you use that template and does not change the layout, margins, font size etc. Else the journal will have to revert all your changes.

Comment: I think it would be really better if you could provide an MWE. Do you use PDFLaTeX? What is the sans-serif font you use? All these questions could be easily answered with an MWE.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: OK, I've done it!

Comment: Your MWE is important, because if you would be able to use the `fontspec` package (which requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX), you could easily use the `Scale` option to match the sizes of different fonts. With PDFLaTeX, this is a bit more tricky, but some packages allow for scaling. See, for example, [Q204921](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204921/47927), [Q652114](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/652114/47927) or [Q284989](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/284989/47927).

Comment: @JasperHabicht, thank you. So would it be fair to say that some packages that provide fonts include a scaling option, but within PDFLaTeX there is no uniform way to impose a font size change for any one font?